# Django ORM, getting variables from three tables

Tags: django, join, orm

I am basically trying to do two joins in one line in Django, but I cannot seem to find a solution. Below you can see the **models.py**.

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    birthdate = models.DateTimeField()
    phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Address(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    city = models.ForeignKey(City,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class City(models.Model):
    zippcode = models.CharField(max_length=10,primary_key=True,unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to filter the people with surname Smith, and show their name, date of birth, their street name and the name of their city.
I came so far:

```
Person.objects.filter(surname='Smith').values('name','birthdate','address__name','address__city__name')
```

This doesn't work because of the last part in values 'address__city__name'. I am trying to figure out how to get the city name in some other way, but I can't seem to figure this out. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? There is no reason for this not to work. I even copy/pasted your code and tested it and it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Your query is correct and must execute.However you can optimize it a bit more by using **select_related**.

```
obj = Person.objects.filter(surname='Kumar').select_related('address','address__city').values('name','birthdate','address__name','address__city__name')
```

[image]